# r Shiny action button and data table output last N rows

Tags: r, shiny

I need help with action button working only once. If you click on button it will shows you graph,table and some text. But if you want to change something on sidebar like a colour it will change and you dont have to press the button... (I need to have: If you want to change something colour,values..you need to always push the action button to confirm it it cant change without button)
Also, I need to show only the last N rows from table `airquality` which depends on `numericID` input. Can anyone help me?

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) { 

  observeEvent(input$gobutton, {
    output$textik <- renderText({
      vypis=c("Zobrazili ste tabuÄ¾ku s", input$numericID, "riadkami a boxplot pre atribÃºt Ozone ste nastavili na farbu ", input$radioID)
      print(vypis)
    })

    output$table <- renderTable(airquality)

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      x    <- airquality[,input$selectID]
      boxplot(x~airquality$Month,  col = input$radioID, border = 'white', main=input$textID)
    })
  })

})

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("DÃ¡ta Airquality"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarPanel(
    numericInput("numericID","PoÄet riadkov tabuÄ¾ky",value=6, min=1, max=100, step=5),
    selectInput("selectID","Vyberte atribÃºt",choices=c(colnames(airquality))),
    radioButtons("radioID","Vyberte farbu grafu", choices=c("yellow","green")),
    textInput("textID","Zadajte nadpis grafu", value ="Nadpis"),
    actionButton("gobutton","Start")
  ),

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(           
    plotOutput("distPlot"),
    tableOutput("table"),
    textOutput("textik")
  )

))
```

Comment: Thank you ben ITs working,Now the bigest problem is that button. I dont know how to make it.. Its like if you change colour after you already prest action button it will changed without pressin the action button again. And always if you change something than you need to press action button and after that everything can change on your inserted inputs in sidebar but it changing automatically.. no need to press the button after first pressing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tomáš - I would recommend avoiding putting your `output` statements inside of `observeEvent`. Instead, I would create an `eventReactive` that will be triggered by your action button. And when this happens, it will store all your needed info in a list, and all of your outputs will be dependent on this list. Here is one way to do this (below is the `server` function only).

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  aq_data <- eventReactive(input$gobutton, {
    list(data = airquality, nID = input$numericID, rID = input$radioID, sID = input$selectID, tID = input$textID)
  }) 

  output$textik <- renderText({
    vypis=c("Zobrazili ste tabuÄ¾ku s", aq_data()[["nID"]], "riadkami a boxplot pre atribÃºt Ozone ste nastavili na farbu ", aq_data()[["rID"]])
    print(vypis)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable(tail(aq_data()[["data"]], aq_data()[["nID"]]))

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    dat <- aq_data()
    boxplot(reformulate("Month", dat[["sID"]]), col = dat[["rID"]], border = 'white', main = dat[["tID"]], data = dat[["data"]])
  })

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ben!